# Storing output of Solve in the variables themselves

Tags: equation-solving

I solved a set of equations with indexed variables using `Solve`. How can I get the output solution to be stored in the variables themselves?
I obtained the results from `Solve` in the form:
`f[1,1,1]->3, f[1,1,2]->5,...`. Now I want to have these indexed variables store their values. That is, to have `f[1,1,1]=3, f[1,1,2]=5` and so on. There are many solutions so doing it manually is not feasible.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please give a MWE to illustrate the issue.

Comment: The solution is of this form: `f[1,1,1]->3, f[1,1,2]->5,...` I want to use these variables `f[1,1,1], f[1,1,2],...` so I want them to have the values obtained from `Solve`. For example, if I do `4f[1,1,1]` I get 12 and so on.

Comment: Try `Set @@@ {f[1, 1, 1] -> 3, f[1, 1, 2] -> 5}`

Comment: @m_goldberg there are too many variables to manually assign if that's what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the output of your `Solve` is stored in a list called `sol`. Then the following will do the trick

```
Set @@@ sol[[1]]
```

Or alternatively

```
sol /. Rule -> Set
```

What both of these end up doing is changing each the `Rule` statements (e.g. `f[1,1,1] -> 3`) to equivalent assignments (e.g. f[1,1,1] = 3).